# Setup for Android Remote mySQL Database Connectivity using PHP Script

Tags: android

I am new to the android and I am working under project developing android application. I want to know the steps to upload PHP Script which is required to connect and perform operations on remote database stored in web server. If anyone know where to place PHP Script on server and what are the changes required in my PHP Script then please correct me.

When I execute below java code on emulator then it simply gives me the error like :
"Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

that means the PHP Script doesn't execute on database i.e. why it returns directly the script only. And because it returns script directly which is in form of string, JSONArray which I have declared does not able to convert it from string.

Please anyone know regarding this problem, then make correct wherever I am making mistakes.

Thank you in advance,

### PHP Script :

```
<?php

  $dbHost = '******';
  $dbUser = '***';
  $dbPass = '****';
  $dbName = '*****';

  if (!mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass)) 
  {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Oh No! Something went wrong connecting to the database: '.mysql_error());
  }
  else if (!mysql_select_db($dbName)) 
  {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Oh No! Something went wrong selecting the database: '.mysql_error());
  }

  $query = "SELECT * 
        FROM usermaster WHERE 
        UserName = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username'])."'";

  if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) 
  {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Oh No! Something went wrong with the query: '.mysql_error());
  }

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
    $output[] = $e;
  }

  mysql_close();

  exit(json_encode($output));

?>
```

---

### Java Code :

```
package com.taseen.apps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestExternalDatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView resultView;
    String s = null;

    String result = null;
    InputStream isr = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new RemoteConnectivity().execute();
    }

    private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            // the year data to send
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "paresh"));

            // http post
            try 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://krishisense.org/PHPScript/getlogin.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            // convert response to string
            try 
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result = sb.toString();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // parse json data
            try 
            {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    s = s + "User Name : " + json.getString("UserName") + "\n"
                            + "Password : " + json.getInt("Password") + "\n"
                            + "User Type : " + json.getString("LoginType")
                            + "\n\n";

                }
            }

            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result1) 
        {
            resultView.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! I found the solution and it works for the above problem. The problem of prompting me to download the file is also resolved. Now the php script which I uploaded on server can be executed and returns the data also, depending on the specified query.

The solution I found is just because I have uploaded a jsp site in that domain and still I was going to execute the php script, so there was a conflict between tomcat(jsp site) and apache(php script). That is why I was being asked to download the file because there was no server available to execute the php script. So it was treated like simple file.

Now to resolve that problem I created a subdomain which will point to a particular directory in my public_html folder under root directory. So when I provide that url in browser then that subdomain will directly point to the folder which I have specified.

For eg. Domain        : example.org
        Subdomain     : download.example.org

To create subdomain for your domain, please go to Domains section in your cpanel, and under that section click on Subdomain icon. Then you will be asked to provide the name for subdomain and the directory to point to that domain. You can also set the redirection also. Later if you want to remove the subdomain, then you can also do that by clicking on remove link.

And also I was making a mistake in providing a correct host name. That I found after clicking on MySQL Databases under Databases section in your cpanel.